# Flutter: persisting app bar with changing title

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am working on my first Flutter app, and I am struggling to find a good solution to this problem. My app has multiple pages and different routes that the user can take. Currently, I am redefining the app bar for every one of these pages which has not been a huge deal since all have been placing on the app bar is the title for every page. I would like to place a button on the app bar for each page that will return the user to the home page, no matter where they are in the app. I also still need to be able to change the title on the app bar on the different pages. I could just redefine this navigation functionality for each page, but intuition tells me that there has to be a better solution, as this would violate the DRY principle. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a new file containing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String appBarText;
  CustomAppBar(this.appBarText);
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        appBarText,
      ),
      leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then anywhere you need you to use your custom app bar import the file then in your scaffold you can use it like a regular app bar

```
import 'YOUR DIRECTORY/CustomAppBar.dart';

Scaffold(
  appBar: CustomAppBar('your title here'),
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I was not aware that you could redefine the functionality of the app bar like this, so very helpful. It also opened my eyes to the possibility of adding functionality to other widgets in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Jamison No problem. If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Done. My bad, this was actually my first time ever posting a question to SO so I did not know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `leading` `IconButton` to your `AppBar` that calls `Navigator.pop()` when pressed. This will return the user to the last page:

```
AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    ),
    title: Text('AppBar'),
),
```

Remember, pages are stored in a view stack. When you push a page using `Navigator.pushNamed()`, you are adding that page *on top of* the initial page. Therefore, a simple `pop` will return you to the home page.

This is also explained in [this Flutter Cookbook recipe](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#4-return-to-the-first-screen).

Also, if you are navigating to a route directly without visiting the initial page first, the initial page is still pushed. As the [documentation for the `initialRoute` property of `MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html) states:

> If the route name starts with a slash, then it is treated as a "deep link", and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are pushed also. For example, if the route was /a/b/c, then the app would start with the four routes /, /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c loaded, in that order. Even if the route was just /a, the app would start with / and /a loaded.

If you have any other questions about routing, feel free to reach out to me.

Comment: I might have not explained my issue well enough, my apologies. I know that in order to return to a previous page, you pop the current page off of the navigation stack. My issue is that I need to be able to return directly to the home page even if i am a few layers deep into a navigation, and I want to be able to do so with the click of a button on a singly defined app bar. I already have the function defined to do this, I just need a way to add it to each page’s app bar without redefining the app bar for each page.

Comment: Then you should do what @Apg recommended and create a widget that acts as a constant AppBar for every page you put it on. The App bar should have a "Home" button that calls `Navigator.pushNamed('/')` to return the user to the home page. The pages on the stack will then automatically be removed to return to the home page.